# How to make another .py file recognize an input from another .py file?

Tags: python, directory

So I have two .py files, **fileA.py** and **fileB.py**.

**fileA.py** will make **fileB.py** run.

But first, **fileA.py** will have a script to ask a folder directory as an input.

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess
import sys
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory

pathcase = askdirectory(title='path to folder')

scripts = [
    'fileB.py'
]

parent = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

for script in scripts:
    script_path = parent / script
    subprocess.call([sys.executable, script_path])
```

How to make **fileB.py** run and recognize the "pathcase" input?

**fileB.py** has:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pvpython
from paraview.simple import *
from fileA import pathcase
casefoam = OpenFOAMReader(registrationName='case.foam', FileName='{}/case.foam'.format(pathcase))
```

What is happening right now is that **fileA.py** runs **fileB.py** and asks again for an input everytime, making a loop.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. Do you want that when you type `python fileA.py`, it actually runs fileB ? Then you  just have to do `import fileB` inside fileA and make sure that the path is correct (it should be by default if your files are in the same folder)

Comment: Also if you want more precise help, make sure to detail your code more precisely. What is the "script that makes fileB.py run" that you talk about ?

Comment: Hey @MateoVial, when fileA.py runs fileB.py, I want to fileB.py recognize ```pathcase```, but instead, it asks for the folder again. My thoughts are that the code in fileB.py restarts fileA.py?

Comment: @MateoVial I edited with the rest of the script in fileA.py.

Comment: I feel like you are leaving out a key part of your code. Please provide us with the code from fileB.py, the code you have right now should not get stuck in a loop.

Comment: @HARRIBO edited with the most important part of it.

Comment: @HARRIBO let's say I run ```fileA.py```, it asks me for a folder, so let's say ```D:/Folder```, then ```fileA.py``` runs ```fileB.py```. I would like to have the same variable "pathcase" that I defined it on ```fileA.py``` in ```fileB.py```, but it asks me again for a folder.

Comment: @Xaix I have left an answer that I think solves your problem :) lmk if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend keeping a `config.py` module to store all of your globally used variables, in this case, pathcase. Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the module then becomes available as a global name. It would work as the following:

**config.py**

```
n = 10
```

**fileA**

```
import config
config.n = 20
```

**fileB**

```
import config
import fileA
print(config.n)
```

This way, your code will stay **elegant**, **readable**, and should fix the problem you are running into. :)